# Generate pedigree for plants in R

Tags: r

Until now I have used the synbreed library to generate the pedigree of my plants. With this code:
`PED <-create.pedigree (dataF $ GENOTYPE, dataF $ MOTHER, dataF $ FATHER, add.ancestors = TRUE))`

But in version 4 of R I can't install the synbreed library, so try trying the kinship2 library but I always get an error since I don't have sex information because they are plants. Someone could give me a recommendation, whatever it is, thank you very much.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming questions rather than recommendations for packages. You are more likely to get a response if you set out your data and code you have tried as well as your expected outcome. Having said that you might find some useful information in the relevant cran task view: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/

Comment: I don't have R4.0, so I can suggest this, the old function you are using is https://rdrr.io/rforge/synbreed/src/R/create.pedigree.r

Comment: source this or copy and paste to create the function. Run it with kinship2 or whatever in the background

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation of `kinship2`, it looks like you can pass 'unknown' as the sex argument:

> sex
> Gender of individual noted in ‘id’. Either character ("male","female","unknown","terminated")
> or numeric (1="male", 2="female", 3="unknown", 4="terminated") data is allowed. For character data the string may be truncated, and of arbitrary case.

([Source](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kinship2/kinship2.pdf).)

I'm not familiar with these packages, so that might be totally off-base.